# Using Tecflare's API to create a new user

Tags: php, api

My code keeps giving me

`SolidAPIReference Err On line 3 Expecting ControlHandler`

Here is my code:

    `include("dev/mainAPIsystem.php");
    using_dev_tool(APP_HANDLE);
    using_dev_tool(APP_API_CONNECT,APP_API_ALL);
    $conn = do_dev_connect(API_HOST,API_PASS);
    $scr = do_dev_command(adduser("mike","Mypassword","Theplan"));
    $conn->doexec($scr);
    $conn->disconnect(0x0000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scr = di_dev_command("command-here");

You forgot $scr.